# Is there a standard way to transform a String into a File considerning the possibility of a URL/URI formatted input String

Tags: java, string, file, url, uri

I would like to obtain the most accurate `File` typed representation of a String that is supposed to refer to a local (existing) file in one of several forms like:

```
String file0 = "/home/my_user/file.txt"

String file1 = "file:///home/my_user/file.txt"

String file2 = "file.txt"; // assuming that the working dir is /home/my_user.
```

Is there a (quasy) single liner using the standard library or perhaps a common third party like apache-commons that would do the trick?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own function for this purpose. Given below is the function definition and test code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String file0 = "/Users/arvind.avinash/file.txt";
        String file1 = "file:///Users/arvind.avinash/file.txt";
        String file2 = "file.txt"; // assuming that the working dir is /Users/arvind.avinash.

        System.out.println(getFile(file0).exists());
        System.out.println(getFile(file1).exists());
        System.out.println(getFile(file2).exists());
    }

    static File getFile(String pathOrUri) {
        URI uri;
        File file = null;
        try {
            uri = new URL(pathOrUri).toURI();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return new File(pathOrUri);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            return new File(pathOrUri);
        }
        if (uri != null) {
            file = new File(uri);
        }
        return file;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
true
true
```

---

**[Update]**

Given below is a more simplified version:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String file0 = "/Users/arvind.avinash/file.txt";
        String file1 = "file:///Users/arvind.avinash/file.txt";
        String file2 = "file.txt"; // assuming that the working dir is /Users/arvind.avinash.

        System.out.println(getFile(file0).exists());
        System.out.println(getFile(file1).exists());
        System.out.println(getFile(file2).exists());
    }

    static File getFile(String pathOrUri) {
        URI uri;
        try {
            uri = new URL(pathOrUri).toURI();
        } catch (MalformedURLException | URISyntaxException e) {
            return new File(pathOrUri);
        }
        return new File(uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for the code. I think it could be simplified a little if you have the time.

Answer (score 0):

You be able to call `new File(x)` on examples 1 and 3 and it should work.

As for #2, you can create a `URI`, and then create `File` from that. In fact I think they all probably will work using URI

```
String fileStr = "file:///home/my_user/file.txt";
try {
  URI uri = new URI(fileStr);
  File f = new File(uri);
} catch (URISyntaxException ex) { ...}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, not sure what the ```try {}``` block is trying to accomplish... probably it does not even compile, or does it.